# import all the required react-native components in a single and file and then export it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import, export

Instead of writing the following code in every reactnative's ".js" file, is it possible to write it in a single file and the export it so that i can use it in other js files just by importing this one file (containing all the component that I need to use)

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Image,
    View
} from 'react-native';
```

Now instead of writing the above code in page1.js, page2.js, page3.js, how do i write it in a single file called "comp.js" and export it from there so that i only have to import comp.js in the page1.js, page2.js and page3.js file

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but I recommend using index.js for that folder instead of that `comp.js`

In a folder you can create index.js and import all related js in that folder so you can import very easy

For example: I have my folder called Components

1. Create `index.js` in the folder `Components`
2. Import and export files

```
import comp1 from './comp1'
import comp2 from './comp2'
import comp3 from './comp3'

export { comp1, comp2, comp3 }
```

3. Import folder instead of each file and select only needed files `import { comp1, comp2 } from '../Components'`

Comment: how about 
```export comp1 from './comp1'
```
and so on..
directly

Comment: @ArnavYagnik, that not works.

You can't name your export directly. You have to use `export {default as comp1} from './comp1'`